# How to add filter form to magento admin grid?

Tags: forms, magento, filtering

How to add a filter form as like report->sales->orders to my custom module. The filtered result should be shown in grid table.I have made the data to be displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Grid.php`, where you are creating columns of grid, you need to add `'filter'=>true`. Like below:

```
$this->addColumn('COLUMN_NAME', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('MODULE_NAME')->__('COLUMN_HEADER_TEXT'),
        'index'     => 'COLUMN_NAME',
        'sortable' => true,    // make sortable column
        'filter'   => true     // make filter column
  ));
```

Hope will help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i need a filter form like report->sales->orders.not column filter.

Comment: OK, you want to add new option under Report->Sales. Like - Order, Tax, Invoice. Check this link will help: http://wrightcreativelabs.com/create-a-custom-magento-report-product-skus-in-new-orders/

Comment: No.I need a filter form like report for my custom module.There are many options under that filter form.result should be displayed in the grid table.

Comment: Please check out this thread - http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/prepared-filter-for-magento-admin-grids/

Comment: @Anu, you need to create custom module as per your requirement, other helpful link: http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/create-custom-reports-in-magento-admin/